# Idempotent completion of an additive category

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an additive category, and a morphism $e: X \rightarrow X$ in it an idempotent, i.e. $e \circ e = e$. We say that $e$ splits, if we can decompose $X = \operatorname{ker}(e) \oplus \operatorname{im}(e)$, and if every idempotent in $\mathcal{A}$ splits, we call it idempotent complete.
Note that there is a similar definition of a splitting idempotent (and idempotent completeness) for general categories, here $e$ is split when it arises as a retraction on a subobject, followed by its inclusion.

My question if the following: How are these two definitions related? To make this more precise:

- Is there an additive category and an idempotent $e$ in it that splits in the second, but not in the first sense? (The other direction should not be possible, I think)
- Is an idempotent complete additive category the same thing as a an additive category that is Cauchy-complete (this is a notion of idempotent complete for enriched categories) as an $\operatorname{Ab}$-enriched category? Or are the two notions distinct?

Comment: I think all of this is well explained on the nlab, eg https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubian+category#general for your first question. For your second, a Cauchy complete Ab-enriched category is also closed under finite direct sums.

Comment: Yes you are right, that solves it - as it seems, both definitions are indeed eqivalent. I also found the [ncatlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category#examples) where it is stated that Cauchy completion for Ab-categories is the same thing as idempotent completion and completion under finite direct sums. However I am still searching through the references there for a proof of this - I'll let you know if I find one.